# Amazon API: Date parameter not working as per documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using postman to do a simple API call to Amazon SES, in the documentation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/CommonParameters.html

section X-Amz-Date, they state that

*For example, the following date time is a valid X-Amz-Date value: 20120325T120000Z*

However when i use my date in that formar I get an error

```
<Message>Invalid date 20120325T120000Z. It must be in one of the formats specified by HTTP RFC 2616 section 3.3.1</Message>
```

so if i look into HTTP RFC 2616 section 3.3.1 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)

they are 3 possible formats

- ```
    Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT  ; RFC 822, updated by RFC 1123
  ```
- ```
    Sunday, 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT ; RFC 850, obsoleted by RFC 1036
  ```
- ```
    Sun Nov  6 08:49:37 1994       ; ANSI C's asctime() format
  ```

It seems to be working with the option 1 and 3, however i keep getting an error

```
<Message>Request timestamp: Wed, 20 Feb 2019 10:22:00 GMT expired.  It must be within 300 secs/ of server time.</Message>
```

I have move the time several minutes back and forward in case my pc time is fast or behind, but i keep getting 300 sec

Is the documentation of amazon wrong?
if the second is the right format, how can i get the server time, my instance is set to n. virginia I used https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/usa/virginia to get the time and use different options but all of them ends with the 300sec error

[image: Sample of time]

[image: Salesforce code]
I assume that should be translated in postman as:

[image: Sample of salesforce to postman]

Comment: Not sure on the date formatting issue but use NTP to sync your system clock https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91792/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-synchronize-time-using-ntp

Comment: Note also that the servers in N. Virginia do not expect you to use their local time.  All of AWS runs on UTC, which is the same thing signified by `GMT` in your date.

Comment: I just cant get it when i use this time: Tue Feb 19 19:33:00 2019 it tells me  It must be within 300 secs, but when i use Wed Feb 20 05:40:00 2019, that it is the current utc time i get: Date must be in ISO-8601 'basic format'. @Michael-sqlbot I have added an image that hopefully helps clarifying the error

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  I cant even perceive the difference in format between the 2 sample dates in order  to get such a different response

Comment: This is interesting.  And confusing.  One thing to check, first: you are specifying the correct API version in your request, using `Version=2010-12-01`, correct?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot no, but, I wrote code in salesforce and it works correclty, and in my code I dont have version, so for testing purposes I am trying to move the api to postman, and I am adding all the headers as my Salesforce code (I Have added a sample), so that is what is more confusing

Comment: In the first postman screenshot, you have used standard http Date header, can you make sure you converted the date to GMT? In the second postman screenshot, you are still using http Date header, but using the ISO8601 format which is meant for the X-Amz-Date header, not the Date header. The Date and X-Amz-Date headers use different standards and X-Amz-Date will override Date

Comment: @SarwarErfan you are right the dates are different it seems the issue was perhaps a weird bug with postman, I initially pick in auth tab, aws and then I change my mind and was using the same as my code, so I think there was a mix of headers and hidden headers that was been passed, I created in a new tab and new set the auth tab, and it work, however when i try to use it for the API iwant i get error Top level element may not be treated as a list